# Sort numbers in lexicographical order of their prime factors

Tags: algorithm, sorting, math, depth-first-search, prime-factoring

I am trying to solve an algorithmic problem which requires me to sort a list of numbers of size N (N <= 1e6) based on the lexicographical order of their prime factors. Each number in the list is in [2,1e6].

[Link](https://dunjudge.me/analysis/problems/245/) to problem.

For example,

```
2 3 4 5 6
```

would be sorted to:

```
2 4 6 3 5
```

Their prime factors are shown below:

```
2 = 2
3 = 3
4 = 2 * 2
5 = 5
6 = 2 * 3
```

**My attempt:**

I am able to devise a correct solution for this by using a O(logn) prime factorization method on each of the numbers and storing this into a 1e6 * 21 2d array because all numbers <= 1e6 can have at most 20 prime factors since 2^20 > 1e6.

Thereafter I sort each of the numbers using the lexographical order of these prime factors.

My program is able to run well under the time limit of 2 seconds but uses too much memory (the memory limit is 32mb).

---

Could someone please advise me on a better way to solve this problem?

p.s. This problem was tagged with "depth-first-search" but I can't see how this would work anyway.

Comment: Depending on which programming language you're using, you may be able to meet the memory limit without changing your approach. There are less than 4 million total factors. So if each factor is 32 bits (4 bytes), that's less than 16MB. In other words, instead of a fixed sized array for each number, use an array that's only big enough to store the factors.

Comment: @user3386109 how would you store the factors of 524288 (2^19)? Or 510510 (2*3*5*7*11*13*17)?

Comment: @MarkRansom I'm suggesting that the OP should use a [ragged array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jagged_array).

Comment: could you please clarify about your "O(logn) prime factorization method on each of the numbers"? Do you build the minimal-factor sieve here?

Comment: @Will Ness I used the fast factorization method which makes use of lowest divisors as mentioned in this link: https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/math/number-theory/basic-number-theory-2/tutorial/

Comment: thanks. so, it *is* the minimal-factor sieve then. no problem, you can adapt Mark's answer to it, I think. BTW it's not log(n) per number; it's (log log n)^2. Which is probably very close in practice. :) But it needs half the size of the original array, space-wise. still, it should be manageable. interesting problem btw. could you give a link to it?

Comment: @Will Ness Thanks for clarifying the time complexity. At the moment, I am unable to implement Mark's answer without a concrete example. I have added the link to the problem source in my post.

Comment: do you want me to post some clarifications in an answer?

Comment: @Will Ness I would be most grateful if you did so.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159513/discussion-between-will-ness-and-lancehaoh).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, a simple modification to my algorithm did the trick. Rather than storing the prime factorization of each integer, I made use of what I already had, which is a prime factorization method that works in O(logn). I created a custom sort method that uses the factorization method to factorize two integers while I compared their prime factors. Hence, the time complexity remained the same and there was no need to store the prime factorization of any integer.

For those curious to know how this fast factorization method works, here is a [link](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/math/number-theory/basic-number-theory-2/tutorial/) (see the method that uses lowest divisors).

For future readers who face the same problem, here is my accepted code:

```
#include<cstdio>
#include<algorithm>

#define FACTOR_LIM (int) 1e6+2 // used by preFactor(n). Defined as <= n <= 1e8

using namespace std;

int lowestDiv[FACTOR_LIM+1], a[FACTOR_LIM], n;

void preFactor(int n) {
    int root = 2;
    for(int i = 2; i*i <= n; i++) {
        if(lowestDiv[i]) continue;
        root = lowestDiv[i] = i;
        for(int j = i*i; j <= n; j+=i) {
            lowestDiv[j] = (lowestDiv[j]) ? lowestDiv[j] : i;
        }
    }
    for(int i = root; i <= n; i++) {
        if(!lowestDiv[i]) {
            lowestDiv[i] = i;
        }
    }
}

bool cmp(const int i, const int j) {
    int x = i, y = j;
    while (x != y) {
        int p = lowestDiv[x];
        int q = lowestDiv[y];
        if (p != q) return p < q;
        x /= p;
        y /= q;
    }
    return false;
}

int main() {
    preFactor(FACTOR_LIM-1);
    scanf("%d",&n);

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    }
    sort(a,a+n,cmp);

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%d\n",a[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This sounds like a partitioning problem to me. The first step would be to partition the array so that the numbers that divide by 2 come first. Then partition *that* group by the ones that divide by 2 a second time. Recurse until you have an empty subgroup. Now do it again with a divisor of 3. Continue up the list of primes until you reach sqrt(1e6) or you've found all the divisors for each number.

Comment: Why sqrt(1e6) in particular?

Comment: @LanceHAOH that's the largest number that could evenly divide into 1e6.

Comment: Hmm. Let's take 22 as an example, 22 = 2 x 11 but sqrt(22) < 5. So we cannot "see" 11. How will this be covered?

Comment: @LanceHAOH 2 is less than 5, so you'll divide by that. Whatever the remainder is will be guaranteed prime. You were correct to call me on this though, it's an edge case.

Comment: @MarkRansom would you mind adding one example for [2,3,4,5,6] ?

Comment: good start (I uv'd), but you need to show how, for {2,3,4,6,8,10}, 6  and 10 will be printed *before* 3. Right now it's **not at all clear** that it'll be so. ---- Also, this will effectively implement factorization via trial-division by primes, with *O( sqrt(n)/log(n) )* time per a number *n*, but OP talks about *O( log n )* factorization (is there even such a thing??).

Comment: @WillNess my intention was to give a starting point, not solve the problem 100%. I think I can make this work recursively like a Quicksort but I haven't come up with the code to prove it. I've never seen this problem before.

Comment: @MarkRansom yes, I fiddled with it in the mean time, and it is doable. I'm just saying it's not immediately apparent from your answer. Plus, the question about complexity...

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already well within your time limit, you just need a more efficient way to store all the prime factors for each number so that you can easily look them up. You can do this with a 2-level lookup table.

In one table, store the numbers up to 1e3 (1000) as you are storing them now. This will require a 1e3 x 10 2d array (1000 x 10 x 4 = 10000 bytes).

To store all the prime factors for numbers up to 1e6 you need to store up to 3 numbers for each one (that's 12 million bytes). To compute the 3 numbers, start with the list of prime factors and multiply them back together until you can't multiply another one without going over 1000. Store that in the first entry, then do the same with remainder and store in the second number and if you have any left over just put it in the 3rd position (you'll never need more than 3 - if you had 4 it would mean the last two multiplied together would be over 1000, which would imply the first 2 multiplied together would be < 1000, in which case they wouldn't be stored separately). If there is a prime factor over 1000 in the list you only need 2 because all the others will multiply to < 1000.

To retrieve the original list of prime factors for an entry take each of your three numbers (which will be prime or composite numbers 1000 or less or prime numbers > 1000), if they are under 1000 look up their prime factors in the small table and if not take them as is, and you can reconstruct the list.

For e.g. to store 515130 (2*3*5*7*11*223)

```
1st number: 210 (2*3*5*7) can't multiply by 11 without going over 1000
2nd number: 11 (prime) can't multiply by 223 without going over
3rd number: 223
```

667023 (3*7*23*1381)

```
1st: 438 (3*7*23)
2nd: 1381 (prime)
```

This will work even if the list of prime factors is unsorted.